# Resharper Getter Setter

Tags: c#, resharper

my variable:

```
private int _myInt;
```

When I'm generating getter/setter with resharper it gives me :

```
public int myInt
    {
        get { return _myInt; }
        set { _myInt = value; }
    }
```

When I click on myInt, refactor -> convert it gives me :

```
    public void setMyInt(int value)
    {
        _myInt = value;
    }

    public int getMyInt()
    {
        return _myInt;
    }
```

Is there a way to get final form without clicking too much, and preferably from variable itself to getMyInt(), setMyInt()  (Skip 2nd phase.)?
I wouldn't mind clicking, but I can't select multiple lines to convert.
VS15, resharper 10.

Comment: why do you want the get and set method? why not rely on (auto) properties? r# will help you with that. Choose refactor => encapsulate field (or CTRL+R+E)

Comment: I got used to it beacuse of java. Besides, It looks ugly as hell when you modify those get/set.

Comment: Does it? It's just another level of indentation, and you get to avoid some code repetition (namely repeating `MyInt` in the function declarations and parameters). (Not to mention the other benefits of properties.)

Comment: Properties are quite a foundation in the language. If you are against it, I guess you will have to produce more boilerplate code, and won't get the most out of brilliant tools like R#. Maybe give it another chance and you might appreciate the language more than you could expect :).

Comment: Use language standards, not arbitrary standards. Please use properties. Any body ever using your code will want to hunt you down  =P

Comment: Funny thing is - r# generating those fields himself, I just want to skip 2nd phase.

Comment: The most likely reason why ReSharper doesn't give you a one-step solution to this problem is that you're writing non-C# style code. I'm assuming you actually put more code into the getters or setters, otherwise why not just go with `public int MyInt { get; set; }` and have the compiler create the backing field for you?

Comment: Additionally, this is basically how C# and .NET does it (properties), you're going to get into a fight with most class libraries out there that expects to find proper properties, like Json serialization, database and entity framework mappings, etc.

Comment: R# gives you the option in case you *need* to convert it to methods. The only reason you'd want to deviate from the coding standard is if you needed to pass the property getter or setter as delegates (which can't be done directly with properties.) I'm not surprised there isn't a way to directly convert without the middle step; it's unconventional.